# How to use horizontal fill in math mode for LyX

Tags: lyx

I am in math mode and I would like to push text (that justifies a step in an equation) to the end of the page. Usually I would apply "Horizontal Fill"; however, this option is removed when I am in math mode. For example, I would like to push the expression (by (3)) to the margin of the page.

[image]

Here is the source for my chain of equations.

```
\begin{eqnarray*}
\text{Hdim}K_{0}\left(\theta\right) & \le &           
\limsup_{i\to\infty}\frac{\log\#\sigma\left(\alpha\right)}{\log n_{k_{i}+1}-\log       
n_{k_{i}}}\\
& = & \limsup_{i\to\infty}\frac{\log a_{k_{i}+1}}{\log n_{k_{i+1}}-\log   
n_{k_{i}}}\qquad\left(\text{by }\left(3\right)\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
```

**MWE**: I would like expressions used to justify steps in a chain of equations/inequalities to appear on the right margin just as (3) does in the following pdf image[image]

Here is the Latex Source for this example.

```
\begin{lem}
\begin{doublespace}
\textup{Let $\alpha\in J$ and $k=\left|\alpha\right|$.} 
\begin{equation}
\#\sigma\left(\alpha\right)\le a_{k+1}
\end{equation}
\end{doublespace}
\end{lem}
```

Comment: Well actually your caption don't let me see well the equations for understand better your issue. Could you bring us a Minimal Working Example of your document for understand you better?

Comment: I've added the Latex Source from my LyX document.

Comment: I asked for a whole minimal working example, not only a portion of the document, but I see you don't use the `amsmath`package or another that improve and ease the work with mathematical equations. I have few ideas, but without a MWE perhaps will be better wait.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\tag*` macro from `amsmath`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
y &= f(x) \tag*{foo}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

You can insert it inside LyX with `Ctrl-L` (Eval Red Text) as LaTeX code: LyX inserts the backslash and insert `tag*{foo}` which will then be collapsed to:

[image]

However, do *not* use the environment `eqnarray`, it has a lousy formatting. Use environment `align` instead.

Comment: Where should the code be inserted, and does it start at \begin or \documentclass{article}? My document class is aricle, and I included the \usepackage{amsmath} to my latex preamble, but I am not sure where/how to implement this. I'm not sure if ERT works in math mode, and I cannot generate a pdf when I paste this code in ERT.

Comment: Write your equation as usual and at the end of the equation

Comment: Herbert, I see how to use this code if my chain of equalities is 1 line, but where to I insert this code if I have a vertical chain of equalities and I want "foo" to appear in one of the rows?

Comment: then at the end of that row